# How to set the user-defined-variable as given output by command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```bash
readlink -f /usr/bin/java
```

I want to set following output to user-defined-value JAVA_HOME
but I don't know how to make it work.

I don't speak English well..
but I spent so much time trying to solve this. T^T

```bash
JAVA_HOME= echo "`readlink -f /usr/bin/java`"
echo $JAVA_HOME

### output : blank line

JAVA_HOME= echo \"`readlink -f /usr/bin/java`\"
echo $JAVA_HOME

### output : blank line

readlink -f /usr/bin/java | JAVA_HOME= 
echo $JAVA_HOME

### output : blank line
```

Comment: Use `JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java)`; see ["How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) Also, I recommend putting your script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and following its recommendations.

Comment: Complementary to Gordon's comment: `realJava=$(realpath "$(command -v java)"); JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-${realJava%/bin/java}}` will set the `JAVA_HOIME` variable to the real path of java, only if `JAVA_HOME` was not previously set.

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks to you, I learned new command 'realpath' and 'command' by your comment. It's really great place here to learn new things!

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the comment. Next time, I will try more to ask questions that do not duplicate.